# ifstream binary read/write only takes char*?

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to write this value to a file correctly. I did a little research on the internet and found this article.

http://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs380/HANDOUTS/cppBinaryFileIO-2.html

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int testVar = 71;
    std::ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("C:/binary.dat", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    outputFile.seekg(0);
    outputFile.write(&testVar, sizeof(testVar));
    outputFile.close();
}
```

What I understand from the article is that the first parameter is a void pointer? which means that it will accept any type? But when I'm typing it out, the intelisense says there is no overload and the first parameter takes type char*.

Am I using the wrong header or something from an older C++ version??

Could really use some help here.
Thanks!

Comment: I have no clue what you're actually asking about?

Comment: This is in regards to outputFile.write() parameters and what i took from the article. I'm looking to write an integer to a file using binary output.

Comment: You can see documentation and an example at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write

Comment: You have to type-cast the int into a char* for ofstream::write() to work.

Comment: So the article that I read is bogus? what happens if i want to save a value that is larger than 255?

Comment: The article is wrong. The value you want to save is interpreted as an array of characters, which is written to tje stream (the second parameter is the size of the array). The value you write doesn't have to be small or numeric. All objects can be viewed as arrays of characters.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the history of development of the functions. Hence, I can't comment on why the arguments are of type `char*` and not `void*`.

To solve your problem...

You can use:

```
outputFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&testVar), sizeof(testVar));
```

Use `reinterpret_cast` while using `istream::read()` also.

Answer (score 0):

You really just need to cast it to char* like was said before, but there are other problems with the code.
seekg() is for input streams, and you are writing an output file. If you meant to clear the line, just open the file with trunc.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int testVar = 71;
    std::ofstream outputFile("C:/binary.dat", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);
    outputFile.write((char*)&testVar, sizeof(testVar));
    outputFile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter is a `char*`.
`char` having size 1 byte signifies byte by byte data and `char*` signifies a block of data.

Hence when writing raw binary data, the data is passed as a `char*` and size of the block.

> Am I using the wrong header or something from an older C++ version??

No it is not the problem as stated it is `char*` and not `void*` that is taken as argument.

**NOTE**  The seekg() member function is for input streams. I think the functionality you needed was seekp()